# Django: Images inside conditional template tags

Tags: django, templates, static, conditional-statements

I'm trying to display an image based on certain conditions in a Django template, but Django doesn't seem to like use of the static tag within a condition.

Code as follows:

```
  <td>
    {% if result.threshold == "normal" %}
      <img src="{% static "face-green-small.jpg" %}" alt="Green"/>
    {% endif %}
    {% if result.threshold == "high" or result.threshold == "low" %}
      <img src="{% static "face-amber-small.jpg" %}" alt="Amber"/>
    {% endif %}
    {% if result.thresdholf == "vhigh" or result.threshold == "vlow" %}
      <img src="{% static "face-red-small.jpg" %}" alt="Red"/>
    {% endif %}">
  </td>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Invalid block tag on line 32: 'static', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I'm sure static is registered, because it's being used earlier in the template.

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the rest of the template, including where you load and use static.

Comment: you need to {% load static %} at the top of your template

Answer (score 1):

Ah .. I've figured it out.

I assumed that {% load static %} would be picked up from the base template it was extending. It wasn't, so adding {% load static %} to the child template cleared it up.